# Cordova Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project

Tags: android, cordova

I can't seem to figure out how to add the android platform using cordova.

I've extracted my android sdk at ~/Development/adt-bundle/sdk and added it to my ~/.bash_profile on my Ubuntu/Linux machine.

Here is my error:

```
$ cordova platforms add android
Creating android project...

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 

/home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at /home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (/home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/platform.js:244:30
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:948:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

Why am I getting this error and what am I doing wrong?